# How to require a gem from background process/console that is in vendor/gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a gem unpacked (youtube_g) in vendor/gems which works ok from Rails when it's loaded.

I need to use this gem when I run delayed_job by calling

```
require 'youtube_g'
```

but I get this error::

```
MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- youtube_g
    from /Users/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /Users/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    from /Users/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

any ideas how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is able to autoload paths so the gem could work without being declared in the gemfile.

But background tasks ay not have this wisdom, try to add this in your gemfile:

```
gem 'youtube_g', :path => "vendor/proper_folder"
```